# Reposition declarations in Netbeans GUIBuilder

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, ide, jcomponent

So, I am designing a small Interface for an application with the netbeans GUI-Builder,

and my problem is, that the position of the Swing-Elements - declarations is not changeable? Or at least I don't know how.

My `ScrollPane` needs the `Textarea` "inside" it as parameter for construction, but in the generated code the `TextArea` is declared below the `Scrollpane`.

I tried changing it with N++ and it worked, but everytime I change the custom code section it replaces the declaration again.

Is there any way to accomplish a custom positioning?

Comment: Why not custom construct the scroll pane in the gui builder "code" section? You can customize it pretty well, and it will autogen the code for you...

Comment: If you drag out of the palette a JTextArea onto the frame, automatically a JScrollPane is generated with the JTextArea under it. The generated code is okay. No need to customize.

Comment: Sigh. I _need_ to customize it because I have an own ScrollPane that requires the Textarea as parameter then created.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, there is unfortunately no way to re-position auto generated code in NetBeans. Have you considered perhaps moving the constructors functionality to another method and calling that after the auto-generated code is finished? Something like `scrollPane.setTextArea(textArea);`?

There is a similar question concerning moving code on the Oracle forums [here](https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=2023857).